# How to return a row only if multiple clauses are met

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working on an application to dispense liquids. here is the organization of the DB

CANISTER:

- canister_id{PK}
- ingredient_id{FK}

INGREDIENT:

- ingredient_id{PK}
- ingredient_name

DRINK:

- drink_id{PK}
- drink_name

INGREDIENTINSTANCE:

- instance_id{PK}
- drink_id{FK}
- ingredient_id{FK}
- amount

Each drink has multiple ingredients(held in the ingredientInstance table), but there are only 12 canisters. I am trying to write an SQL command that will gather all drinks that have ALL of their required ingredients currently in canisters.

So far, this is what I have.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Drink.drink_name
FROM Drink, ingredientInstance, Canister
WHERE (((ingredientInstance.drink_id)=[Drink].[drink_id])
AND ((ingredientInstance.ingredient_id) 
IN (select ingredient_id FROM Canister)));
```

However, this is returning all drinks that have even a single ingredient available. What I am looking for is a way to ensure that for *every* associated ingredient in ingredientInstance, it is currently in a canister.

For example, let's say that **drink1** requires **ingredient1** and **ingredient2**. I want it to appear in the result if both of those ingredient IDs are present in the Canisters, but not if only one or zero ingredients are in the canister.

I'm sure it's something obvious, but I can't think of how to do this.

Comment: What you want is called relational division. Take a look at this question: [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of a set-within-sets query.  I advocate using aggregation with a `having` clause for this:

```
select drink.drinkname
from IngredientInstance ii join
     Drink d
     on ii.DrinkId = d.Drinkid left join
     Canister c
     on ii.IngredientId = c.INgredientId
group by drink.drinkname
having sum(iif(c.IngredientId is null, 1, 0)) = 0;
```

This is joining `IngredientInstance` and `Drink` just to get the drink name.  It is then doing a `left join` to the `Canister` table.  This keeps all the ingredients in the drinks along with matching ingredients (if any) in the canisters.  If an ingredient is missing from `Canister`, then it has a NULL `ingredientId`.

The `group by` looks at the ingredients by drink.  The final `having` clause counts the number of missing ingredients, and only returns drinks with no missing ingredients.

Answer (score 1):

```
select d.* from drink d inner join
(select i.drink_id, sum(case when c.canister_id is null 1 else 0 end) as fullcanister
from ingredientinstance i left join canister c on c.ingredient_id=i.ingredient_id 
group by i.drink_id) as id on id.drink_id=d.drink_id and id.fullcanister=0
```

Comment: . . This doesn't work.  All the `where` clause does is turn the `left outer join` into an `inner join`.  In other words, it will returns drinks that have *any* ingredient in the canister table, as opposed to all ingredients in the table.